# tbl_summary error: dims [product 18] do not match the length of object [27]

Tags: r

I am attempting to run tbl_summary on a data frame and keep getting this error when I pipe in the add_overall() function.  I have used both functions elsewhere in my code on other data frames and do not get the error.

[My Data](https://github.com/LWalker20/AdverseEffects/blob/main/adverseEffects.csv)

My code:

```
select(adverseAll, c(supplement, event, grade, attribution, duration2, outcome)) %>%
    tbl_summary(by = supplement, statistic = list(c(duration2) ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
                digits = list(c(duration2) ~ 2),
                label = list(event ~ "Adverse Effect", grade ~ "Severity", attribution ~ "Attribution", duration2 ~ "Duration", outcome ~ "Outcome")
  ) %>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**Supplement**") %>%
   add_overall(last = TRUE)
```

The exact error:

```
Error in attributes(vec) <- attributes(x$meta_data$df_stats[[which(x$meta_data$variable %in%  : 
  dims [product 18] do not match the length of object [27]
```

When I remove the add_overall() function, the output looks like this:
[Output without overall column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlkrl.png)

I have tried removing NA values and using factor and character data types. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to get the last version of `gtsummary`. `remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/gtsummary")`. Your code works for me.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by exporting the dataframe and rereading it, then running tbl_summary with the new df.